# How are HIDs (keyboard,joypad) created and mapped?

Tags: electronics

I am creating an electronic device that has a 4 position rotator switch and a SPST Momentary ON push button. For the knob, I plan for position 0 to be low (OFF). Position 1-3 are high (ON). But I want these positions to equate to a different signal so they each have different values. When push button is pressed, it sends a high (ON) signal.

Can someone point me into slightly setting up the circuit to accomplish this?
And how can I create a remapper program (preferably in C++) that detects the HID device and allows the end-user to remap the pushbutton signal to any QWERTY key? I want replicate this process for each input of my device.

Comment: Why not have the device send the appropriate key in the first place?

Comment: I want people to be able to remap the input, instead of just having a static key input.

Comment: And? Store the button-to-key mapping in EEPROM, and write a utility to change it.

Comment: I'll go with this example. I have a device that has one push button. I will program it to when the button is pressed, it sends a "generic" value to the computer. Now let's say I give this device to a friend, and he cannot re-program the device itself. How can I make it to where I have a computer software that can detect the "generic" button input and map it to whatever the friend wants to assign it to?

Comment: You'll need to write a driver that intercepts the generic HID message and translates it into an API call that the OS will understand. For every OS. It is much easier to write a program that uses a generic USB library to communicate with the device and tell it what each button should map to, and you only need to write it for one OS and publish the protocol for people who use the other OSes to use if they like.

Comment: Okay thanks. How would I go about coding that generic message in Arduino?

Comment: You wouldn't, because Arduino doesn't let you do that. Look at Atmel Studio and its USB examples, and do all the USB reading you can.

Answer (score 1):

When the Arduino sends data to the computer using the HID protocol it sends what is called a *HID Report*. That is basically an array of numbers in a pre-defined format that correspond to what the computer is expecting.

In the case of keyboard events it sends a *HID Keyboard Report*

[image]

It can send events for up to 6 keys at once along with up to 8 *meta* keys.  How those key events are interpreted are down to the *Keyboard Mapping* used on the computer.  This is the setting (usually in the *Language* or *Regional* settings of the computer) that defines the layout of your keyboard - UK, US, French "AZERTY", etc.

While it is possible to create custom key mappings in many operating systems it is usually a very difficult and involved task. Also the mapping takes effect for every keyboard attached to the system, including the one you type on. So changing the mapping at will is probably not a good idea since it could break your normal keyboard usage.

So how would you go about doing what you want to do?  Well, my recommendation is not to do it on the computer, but to do it on the Arduino.  The Arduino has multiple interfaces available at once. As well as the HID interface for keyboard and mouse it also has the CDC/ACM interface for emulating serial. You can use both of these at once quite happily.  So you can use that USB serial interface to configure the way the Arduino works - including what key code to send for any particular event.  You could even write an easy-to-use GUI in Visual Basic or something that communicates with the Arduino over serial to adjust the settings.  How you do that communication (what protocol you come up with) is entirely up to you.

---

As for the hardware side of things - all you really need is just the switches / buttons and wire.  Just follow the on-line tutorials (there's millions of them) for connecting switches and buttons to the Arduino. Enable the internal pullups, and connect the switch between the I/O pin and ground.  For the rotary switch you will have 4 inputs and 1 output, so connect the 4 inputs to I/O pins and the 1 output to ground.

Comment: Is this sort of similar to how joypads work? What I'm trying to understand is how joypads can be remapped using software. For instance, Button 1 can be assigned to key F or key 4. I want to be able to replicate this with Arduino, as I will write a program to allow this remapping. So after reading this comment, can you kindly confirm that your post will accomplish this task.

Comment: All USB HID devices send HID reports. The format of each report for each device is different as befits the device. What is this "joypad" that you are on about?

Comment: The joypad is for video games. I'm trying to understand how games can detect a gamepad/joypad is connected and then allows you to assign a key per button.

Comment: @O.J.: Gamepads have their own HID report format.

Comment: @O.J. The game pad sends a report in its own format with its own numbers in the various fields. It's then up to the game what it does with those numbers. Windows doesn't really do anything much with the game pad - it just presents the numbers sent by it to the game. With a keyboard it is different because windows handles the incoming reports and maps them to key events.

Comment: Understood. So my overall result is to be able to create an API in C++ that can read the switch positions, etc.. Functions like Device.isConnected() and Device. GetSwitchPos() and Device.isButtonPressed().

Comment: @O.J.: If you're generating standard HID reports then the standard HID drivers will handle them. That is why I made the comment about having the device generate the correct report and having the software tell it which reports to generate. Otherwise you will have to go *fully* custom with your HID implementation.